Can someone please explain the detailed mechanism of function call without any argument?
Here, the calling line np.pad(a, 2, pad_with) works magically!. Not able to find the corresponding python PEP document.
    >>> def pad_with(vector, pad_width, iaxis, kwargs):
    ...     pad_value = kwargs.get('padder', 10)
    ...     vector[:pad_width[0]] = pad_value
    ...     vector[-pad_width[1]:] = pad_value
    >>> a = np.arange(6)
    >>> a = a.reshape((2, 3))
    >>> np.pad(a, 2, pad_with)
    array([[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
           [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
           [10, 10,  0,  1,  2, 10, 10],
           [10, 10,  3,  4,  5, 10, 10],
           [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
           [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]])


What is the hidden syntax in details? When should we use or avoid its abuse?
I knew how to use default arguments and *args and **kwargs for optional arguments, but not familiar with such a case where the call np.pad(a, 2, pad_with) does not use () either and still works as expected.
NOTE: It might be partially answered by this post, but the procedures when stepping inside help with understanding its usage.
EDIT: Thanks for helpful comments. With almost out of practice from c-learning (many years back), the pointer power is memory addressing, but is it the same mechanics applying here?

there is not syntax magic, You can get function's name (without ()) and later use () to execute it. e.g. show = print ; show("Hello World"). And this allows to send function as another parameter to other function, and other function can execute it when it needs it. It is used in many languages - and function's name without () and without arguments often is called callback

BTW: some built-in functions also use it - eg. sorted() can use len() to sort strings by lengths sorted(list_of_strings, key=len). Often we use lambda to create short function for this - sorted(list_of_strings, key=lambda x:len(x))

See also First-class function - Wikipedia

BTW: it is also used to assign function to widgets in GUI frameworks - tkinter.Button(..., command=my_function), tkinter.bind('KeyPress', my_function).  To execute function in another thread. threading.Thread(target=my_function), etc. And all of then may later use () to execute this function later (when they will really need it).

As already mentioned by @furas, there is no magic. The line np.pad(a, 2, pad_with) is a call to the pad function, with three parameters: a vector object (a), an integer value (2), and a reference to a function (pad_with). This allows the np.pad function to manipulate the first two parameters by calling a function provided by the caller.

"the pointer power is memory addressing, but is it the same mechanics applying here" — Sort of, but not really. Somewhere down in the implementation pointers will be playing a role, but with Python as a high level language, that's not how to think about it correctly here. Functions are simply callable objects, and you can pass them around like any other object, and call them later from anywhere else.
